# Cheerio duplicate information

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I have created a scraper, that reads some information from a website.

Thats the html I am reading:

```
<div class="event-meta">
   <div class="event-meta-block animate-onscroll">
      <i class="icons icon-calendar"></i>
      <p class="title">Start Date - End Date</p>
      <p>
         02/12/2020                                                 
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="event-meta-block animate-onscroll">
      <i class="icons icon-clock"></i>
      <p class="title">Start Time - End Time</p>
      <p>
         17:30                                                   
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="event-meta-block animate-onscroll">
      <i class="icons icon-location"></i>
      <p class="title">Event Location</p>
      <p><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=41.861483031307,2.6636006533772">Biblioteca Joan Vinyoli</a></p>
   </div>
   <div class="event-meta-block animate-onscroll">
      <i class="icons icon-ticket"></i>
      <p class="title">Cost</p>
      <p>Gratuït</p>
   </div>
   <div class="event-meta-block animate-onscroll">
      <i class="icons icon-globe"></i>
      <p class="title">Website</p>
      <p>
         <a style="word-wrap: break-word;" target="_blank" href="https://www.culturascf.cat/ca/programacio/c/2006-sessio-virtual-maite-carranza--trobada-dels-c.html">https://www.culturascf.cat/ca/programacio/c/2006-sessio-virtual-maite-carranza--trobada-dels-c.html</a>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="event-meta-block animate-onscroll">
      <i class="icons icon-share"></i>
      <p class="title">Share This</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to obtain the Event Location. In that case I am trying to get `Biblioteca Joan Vinyoli`. I store that data in field named: location:

```
location: $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(2).find(':not(.title)').text().trim(),
```

Is duplicating this information and location store the information like this: `Biblioteca Joan VinyoliBiblioteca Joan Vinyoli`

Thats the function that fetch the information:

```
async function fetchEvent(url) {
    return axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        const dataText = $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(0).find(':not(.title)').text().trim().replace(/\s/g, "");
        let dataInici, dataFinal;
        if(dataText.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
            dataInici = moment(dataText.split('-')[0], 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
            dataFinal = moment(dataText.split('-')[1], 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
        }
        else {
            dataFinal = moment(dataText, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
            dataInici = moment(dataText, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
        }
        return {
            idEvent: $('link[rel="shortlink"]').attr('href').trim(),
            link: url,
            title: $('#content .col-lg-12  h1').text(),
            content: $('#content .p-tb .event-single .col-lg-9').html(),
            endDate: dataFinal,
            startDate: dataInici,
            hora: $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(1).find(':not(.title)').text().trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '),
            location: $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(2).find(':not(.title)').text().trim(),
            locationUrl: $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(2).find('a').attr("href"),
            preu: $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(3).find(':not(.title)').text().trim(),
            web: $('.event-meta').find('.event-meta-block').eq(4).find(':not(.title)').text().trim(),
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return null;
    });
}
```

I don't understand why is duplication the info and storing `Biblioteca Joan VinyoliBiblioteca Joan Vinyoli`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the text from that `a` tag:

```
$('p:contains("Event Location") + p a').text()
```

Or the text from the `p`:

```
$('p:contains("Event Location") + p').text()
```

The way you did it you were getting the text from the `a` plus the text from the `p`.